# Set Closed under addtion and multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set of rational numbers that is closed under addition and multiplication, that have the property that every rational number $r$ exactly has one of the following  $r\in S,\ -r\in S,\ r=0$

prove that

a)  $0\notin S$

b)  that all positive integer belong to $S$

c)  $S$ is the set of all positive rationals

I don't have an idea where to start a,b. with c, I proved it with contradiction, let $S$ have a negative rational number b: $b=\dfrac{x}{m}$, since $S$ is closed under multiplication then, $x\in S$ . Also by part b  $ \exists\ y\in S\ ∶\ x+y=0$ However, this contradicts the part a.

Hints will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think part (c) is true. For instance, let $S$ be all the positive rational numbers. This satisfies the condition you list.

Comment: Is it a typographical mistake in part c? Is it "$S$ is the set of all positive rationals"?

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, I think it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(a)** Let $0\in S$ then you see all of three them hold together.

**(b)** First show that $1\in S$.

$1\neq 0$ so either $1\in S$ or, $-1\in S$. But if $-1\in S$ then the closure property of multiplication gives $(-1)\cdot(-1)=1\in S$. Then from closure property of addition gives $1+(-1)=0\in S$, which is contradiction. Thus $1\in S$.

Hence from closure property of addition any positive integer $n=1+1+\dots+1$ ($n$ times) $\in S$.